# In New Relic RPM, I get reports with an Apdex index listed. What is the subscript meaning?

Tags: performance-testing, newrelic

This sounds ridiculous, but New Relic RPM reports an Apdex index in a form like this:

> 0.92(3.5)

Where the 3.5 is subscripted.

What does the 3.5 mean? I can't find the definition anywhere, and yet there it is in my reports, staring me in the face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bracketed/subscripted number is the threshold (in seconds) for your Apdex score. So, in your case, if the full application response (page load) is less than 3.5s then that satisfies the requirement. If your app responds slower than the threshold then your Apdex score is impacted.

This threshold is customizable, so you can select what is appropriate for your application type.

You can [read more about Apdex](https://newrelic.com/docs/general/apdex) in our docs.

Answer (score 2):

The sub-scripted number is your target response time for that tier. On the user agent (browser) the high water mark is 7 seconds. You should check US-Only and make this number 2 to 4 seconds to be world class.

The app server tier must respond much faster. The high water mark default that NR sets is .5 seconds or 500 milliseconds, a world class page buffer flush would be in the 50-200 ms on average.

Remember all this information is about aggregated averages and not instance data which will have many outliers and have a broad distribution.

Comment: That's an interesting angle. Do you suggest checking US-only because "if you track only US-located browser performance, everywhere else's performance can be blamed on *external* network issues?"

Comment: It would apply well to most users whose networking infrastructure budget cannot reasonably include adding resources to alleviate the performance cost of overseas access (CDN usage, geologically distributed servers, etc.).  After excluding overseas metrics, newrelic would be exclusively showing issues that _can_ be addressed to the benefit of all users.  However, I'm not sure that's an appropriate assumption to make today, given the increasing prevalence/dropping cost of exactly those kinds of resources (especially CDNs).